# How to get sorted output from counsel-git-grep with ivy?

Tags: git, ivy

When using `git-grep`, the output isn't sorted alphabetically which makes navigating the results more tedious then it should be.

Is there a way to sort the output?

I checked `git-grep` and it seems there are no options to do this from within `git` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Posting an answer to my own question, it's a works albeit a little hacky.

This simply pipes git-grep to sort.

Create an executable shell script wrapper for git: `~/.config/emacs/bin/git_sorted`

```
#!/bin/bash
exec git ${1+"$@"} | sort -V
```

And in your `emacs.d/init.el`:

```
(setq
  counsel-git-grep-cmd-default
  "~/.emacs.d/bin/git_sorted --no-pager grep --full-name -n --no-color -e %S")
```

---

`sort -V` happens to sort line numbers correctly (`-n`, `-h`... don't).

Note, it would be nice if there was a way to only sort the file-list which git-grep uses, instead of having to sort the entire output.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the output before and after. I'm just curious